# Laurent Series of $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ around $0<|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have to find the Laurent Series of $$f(z) = \frac{e^z}{z(z^2+1)}$$ which has singularities $z=0$ and $z=\pm i$. I know that $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ and that $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$ for $|z|<1$. In the solutions they say that using these two known series I can find $$\frac{1}{z^2+1} = 1-z^2+z^4-z^6+...$$ but how do I find it from them?

Comment: oh wait maybe cause $\frac{1}{z^2+1} = \frac{1}{1-(-z^2)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-z^2)^n$?

Comment: Yep, that's the way.

Comment: Can I, in general then, transform any expression of the form $\frac{1}{1+g(z)} =\frac{1}{1-(-g(z))} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-g(z))^n$?

Comment: Yes, this is valid when $|g(z)|<1$.

Comment: oh wow, now I understand why the geometric series is stressed so much in the books! Thank you, should I close the question?